# Spring JUnit test case failed

Tags: java, spring, junit, testcase

I try to run a JUnit test case for `ProductDAO` class, that is part of the spring web application. But it still fails. I am not sure by my test-context.xml file.

I have `ProductDAOImplTest` class in path `src/test/java` and mentioned `ProductController` class in the stacktrace  is saved in a path `src/main/java`.

*ProductDAOImplTest*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/test/resources/test-context.xml")
@Transactional
public class ProductDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testEdit() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetByPage() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

*test-context.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- JDBC -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

*Stacktrace*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest com.myapp.controller.ProductController.request; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:106)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest com.myapp.controller.ProductController.request; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: I think your `file:src/test/resources/test-context.xml` should be available as `çlasspath:test-context.xml`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing currently is fine, although I would say it is more of an integration test than a unit test.

My main suggestion would be to only bring up parts of the system that you absolutely need for the component under test, e.g. the `ProductDAO`.

You already seem to be doing this to a certain extent but what may also help is reducing the scope of your `component-scan` to where you keep your DAOs, e.g.:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.dao" />
```

This would avoid picking up higher-level components such as Controllers and Service.

You could then rename the context to `test-dao-context.xml` and use it in all your other DAO tests.

When you come to integration testing your Services you could then have a `test-service-context.xml` context which imports `test-dao-context.xml` allowing you to test from the service to the database without too much repetition of bean definitions.

Comment: Thanks, the change of package for component scan resolved the problem. Is the suggested way a standard of the spring framework or your trick?

Comment: @misco I can't say if it's standard, but it's worked well for me so far. I'm glad you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 27):

The error is in the stack trace

> Could not autowire field: private **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** com.myapp.controller.ProductController.request; ... 
>       No matching bean of type [**javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**]

The problem is that simple Spring tests run with the bare Spring apprlication context, without Spring Web Application context capabilities. So HttpServletRequests, Servlet Context and other features are not available in this case.

Try adding [`@WebAppConfiguration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html) annotation to the test class.

Please note, that this option is available only in Spring 3.2+ versions.

In the older versions of Spring you'll need to invent something to make  this interface implementations available in the application context(the most straightforward thing is to expose MockServletContext class and/or HttpServletRequest interface as beans for tests).

Also please note that the code that uses session scope beans is usually controller specific and belongs to [web application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring) and I believe that it will be the best practice to test controllers in separate tests with the `@WebAppConfiguration`, but leave the tests of the plain old beans and services belonging to the root application context in the simple application contexts, i.e. without `@WebAppConfiguration`.

Just to be clear `ProductDAO` belongs to the root application context, and `ProductController`  belongs to the web application context, so their definitions should be placed in different xml files. `ProductDAO` test should point to the xml of the *root app context only* and contain no `@WebAppConfiguration`.

As for `ProductController` test should point to both root app context and web app context xml files (see [How to Setup web application context in Spring MVC test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940941/how-to-setup-web-application-context-in-spring-mvc-test) for examples) and be annotated with  `@WebAppConfiguration`

Answer (score 4):

Your unit test setup make me (very) nervous. You're trying to bootstrap everything including hibernate, transaction manager and component scanning. You almost need your own container to do this.

Typically a good unit test focuses on one class only per test class, all its dependencies are mocked using libraries such as Mockito

Comment: I am beginner in spring testing, so how should look the correct unit test setup?

Comment: The test in the question is not a unit test, but there is nothing wrong with it -  it's an integration in-container test that tests Spring context configuration and the beans(JUnit is a just a tool to run the test in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what gerrytan and Jonathan wrote. I'd also suggest taking a look at [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) for easier mocking.